# Customize Context Menu Based on DOM value

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, contextmenu

I want to Customize Context Menu into My Application, I need to append the DOM element's value with the Context Menu Item.

for that I am trying something like this::

```
$.contextMenu({
            selector: 'td > .InvoiceNumber_Sale',
            callback: function (key, options) {
                var m = "clicked: " + key;
                var temp = $(this);
                 if (key == "Rebate") DoReverse($(this).attr('data-val'));

            },
            items: {
                "CreditNote": { name: "Credit Note For " + $(this).attr('data-val') }
            }
        });
```

But I am not getting Menu as "Credit Note For xxxx".
can Anyone please help me on this problem.